# Split a numpy column into two columns and keep them in the original array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, which has 3 columns.  There are 100,000 rows, but here are the first two:

```
 burger flipper  part time  12-5.00
 spam flipper    full time  98-10.00
```

The problem is, the job codes (12 and 98) have somehow gotten combined with the hourly wage (5.00 and 10.00).

Is there a simple way in numpy to split this column into two, and get rid of that unnecessary '-' character, as in:

```
 burger flipper  part time  12  5.00
 spam flipper    full time  98  10.00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it using `hstack`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['burger flipper',  'part time',  '12-5.00'],
             ['spam flipper',    'full time',  '98-10.00']])
a = np.hstack((a[:,:2], map(lambda x: x.split('-'), a[:,2])))
print a
```

Output:

```
[['burger flipper' 'part time' '12' '5.00']
 ['spam flipper' 'full time' '98' '10.00']]
```

---

A bit of explanation:

1. The function [numpy.hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) allows you to horizontally stack multiple numpy arrays. For example,

   ```
   np.hstack((a[:,[0,1]], a[:,[2]]))
   ```

   produces the original array `a` with three columns. Note the use of brackets in `a[:,[2]]`, `[a:,2]` will not work as it produces a single dimensional array (`len(a[:,2].shape)` equals 1).
2. The `map` statement apply a function `lambda x: x.split('-')` to the problematic column (i.e. the 3rd column) of the array. Each call to the lambda function returns a list containing the separated job codes and wage, such as `['12', '5.00']`. Thus, the `map` statement produces a list of list which looks like `[['12', '5.00'], ['98', '10.00']]`. This can be converted to a numpy array with 2 columns when being fed to `hstack`.

The code `hstack` first two columns of the original array with the list of list obtained via `map`, resulting in an array similar to what you want in the end.

Comment: You can use `np.char.split(a[:,2], '-')` instead of `map` and `lambda`.

Comment: um...I hate to be obnoxious...but could you please explain a bit of the code?  I'm not too good with numpy and this appears pretty difficult.

Comment: He is making 2 arrays. One has the first 2 columns. The other the last, split into 2 columns using normal Python mapping and split. Then he joins them.

Answer (score 1):

`map(lambda x: x.split('-'), a[:,2])` is now giving a **list** instead of two columns leading to the following error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Needed to change the previous code to:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([['burger flipper',  'part time',  '12-5.00'],
             ['spam flipper',    'full time',  '98-10.00']])
a_newcolumns = np.hstack((map(lambda x: x.split('-'), a[:, 2]))).reshape(a.shape[0], 2)
# need to reshape the list into a two column numpy array
a = np.hstack((a[:, :2], a_newcolumns))
print a
```